# Paypal : Recurring payment with chained payment

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have a requirement to implement a payment scenario, where there is one sender and multiple receivers. I need to do that in recurring manner. Basically I need to do chained payment recursively using **PayPal**.

I have tried to implement recursive payment manually. But it is not possible as we need authentication token, that is not possible with cron job or something.

Any help would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to make an affiliate system ?

Comment: Not exactly affiliate system. But concept is same.

Comment: I did something similar but i used to do all the working from PHP then called the paypal API where the payments took place. I tried something similar to what you are trying to do with a pyramid system but in the end I ended up calling the API multiple times.

Comment: We have been thinking the same, as there is no other way. We tested with normal chained payment and calling API multiple times. Both does separate transactions. That means in the background same thing is going on. Thanks by the way.